# Apply different style to app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I want to create android app in which user can set custom theme, Like blue, and red. I have created 2 `Activities`, From `Activity-1` user can select color. But is it possible to change app theme programmatically?

My styles are:

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_color</item>
</style>

<style name="RedTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_red</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_red</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_red</item>
</style>
```

My toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="@color/color_primary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I tried using `setTheme(R.style.RedTheme)` but it does not change Toolbar color.

Please suggest me.

Thank you.

Comment: set theme after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) and before setContentView(...) in your activity

Comment: but i want to set it on users wish i.e. on button click

Comment: on button click may be you need to recreate activity by destroying previous instance may be and when is your button click same activity or different

Answer (score 0):

Use this when you cant to create your activity:

```
if (...) {
    getApplication().setTheme(R.style.BlackTheme);
} else {
    getApplication().setTheme(R.style.LightTheme);
}
```

Comment: its not changing the toolbars color

Comment: Change in the Manifest the style theme

Comment: but how can i change it in manifest when user select desired theme?